# What are #1, #3, #324 Wood Pegs

Tags: terminology, toy

I'm planning on making a rocking tractor from the [Cherry Tree plans](http://www.cherrytreetoys.com/Rocking-Tractor-Plan-P5018.aspx) , which call for #1, #3, #57, and #324 wood pegs. Does anybody know what these are exactly? The wood toy parts supplier web pages I've looked at don't use numerical notations like this for pegs.

Yes, I know I could make a guess from looking at the plans and pictures, or I could just order the parts kit that Cherry Tree sells, but I'm curious where these numbers are coming from, so if anybody could clue me in, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I couldn't find them on the page but is it possible those value are proprietary to Cherry Tree and corresponds to their own part catalog? This would be useful for Cherry Tree as it encourages you to make more purchases from them and in general so that the build is done to their specifications. Is that the only information it provides? Those pegs surely have imperial values as well. Searching does not show anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are part numbers from Cherry Tree.  When you go to their [search page](http://www.cherrytreetoys.com/Search.aspx) notice that each item has a part number showing in plain black text.  Most of the numbers look kind of like they come from a master list of catalog parts, but some are real simple like 1, 3 or 324.

I did a search for "peg" and found part 1, a "multi use peg" on page 9; part 3, "wood axle peg" on page 15; 324 "wooden axle peg" on page 17.  I did not look for part 57 and will leave that up to you to find.

Comment: Argggh... I didnt look close enough. Good catch.